# Jetbrains PHPstorm 2019.3.3 warns me I have a duplicated jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I fix this warning about the duplication? Is there any better way to do this process for the interaction on the database and front end forms? Also are there any additional improvements that I could add to this work to make it flow better?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function authenticate(mode) {
    if (mode === "Login") {
      let User_email = $("input#log_User_email").val();
      let Password = $("input#log_Password").val();

      let error_collector = "";
      let $log_response = $("div.box_response p#log_response");
      $log_response.html("");

      if (User_email.length <= 0)
        error_collector += "Please enter a user email.";
      if (Password.length <= 0)
        error_collector += "Please enter a user password.";

      if (error_collector !== "") {
        $log_response.html(error_collector);
      } else {
        $log_response.html("Logging in");

        $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "Resources/PHP/Processes/UserLogin.php",
          data: {
            User_email: User_email,
            Password: Password
          },
          success: function(response) {
            if (response === "Success") {
              window.location = "details.php";
            } else {
              $log_response.html(response);
              $("input#log_Password").val("");
            }
          }
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: Which selector is marked as duplicated?

Answer (score 1):

> How can fix this warning error for the duplication

Hopefully PHPstorm told you which one! In this case the selector you've duplicated is `$("input#log_Password")`

```
let Password = $("input#log_Password").val();
...
$("input#log_Password").val("");
```

You can remove the duplication by saving the value of the selector in the first instance at the point you read the password value, then reusing it later when you want to set the value i.e.

```
const $Password = $("input#log_Password");
let Password = $Password.val();
...
$Password.val("");
```